# Find the height of a PDF inside an Iframe with an Ipad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, pdf, iframe

I have an issue to get the height of a PDF inside an Iframe for an Ipad in Safari.

I got a workaround for the PDF scrolling problem, but since the PDF inside the Iframe will changes, I need to find a solution to get dynamically the height of each PDF.

This is the Iframe:

```
 <div id="container" style="height: 625px; width: 620px; overflow: auto; float:right;">
      <iframe id="pdfFrame" height="1500px" width="620px"></iframe>
 </div>
```

And I add the `src` with:

```
 $('#pdfFrame').attr('src', 'test.pdf');
```

So I try to get the height with the `contents()` function:

```
$("#pdfFrame").load(function() {
     $("#pdfFrame").contents("???").height();       
});
```

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide some more explanation like are you using iframe src attribute like `src="http://blah/blah/blah.pdf"` to load the pdf in iframe

Comment: Here I added some infos.

Comment: what do you mean by `height of each PDF`?

Comment: It's the height of the document. I wanted to use the `contents()` function to show me the height of the embed PDF. It works on Firefox (desktop), but show `undefined` on Safari Ipad.

Comment: may be the problem is elsewhere or i am still not able to get what your problem is because it is working when i tested it  in windows safari (changing user agent to safari ipad).    `$("#pdfFrame").load(function() {
     alert($("#pdfFrame").contents().height());       
});`  this gives an alert of  `1500`